# Reading (and usage) of 他: when is it 【た】, when is it 【ほか】?

Tags: grammar, readings

他 is one of these common words that still to this day confuses me...

My general assumption is that:

- used as a prefix, it should always be read 【た】, e.g.: 他人【たにん】
- when treated as a "substantive" (that is essentially, followed by の), it is 【ほか】: 他【ほか】の人【ひと】(?)

But then, some expressions crop up, like 他の物, which my dictionary indicates as read 【たのもの】, and make me doubt whatever little I have deduced so far.

Could anybody settle the た/ほか rules once and for all (and point out any nuance in meaning, if they exist, between the two usages)?

Comment: Aged people sometimes read `他` as 'た' and `等` as 'とう'.

Comment: @sawa: you mean instead of 'ほか'? Are there any rules, though (cases where it's always 'た' or always 'ほか')?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Cases where it is always 'た' is just like you mentioned. Cases where it is 'ほか' can be optionally read as 'た'.

Comment: @sawa: if that's all there is to it and you care to make your comment an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: The biggest one that confuses me is その他.  I've seen it read both ways and I don't know which one is right.  And this appears *everywhere*, especially on garbage/recycling bins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right about when to read it as `た`. The cases where it is read as `ほか` is correct, but some (mainly aged) people optionally read it as `た`. Similarly, `等` is read as `など` or `とう`, but some aged people read it as `とう` instead of `など`.

Comment: btw just to clarify, do you mean that (in the cases when it is pronounced as ほか) if we were to pronounce ほか as た, it would sound as if we are from the "older generation" ?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: Since we are on the precisions: what about my example above, 他の物? WWWJDIC also reads it as たのもの... Is that an obsolete reading, or just an exception?

Comment: @sawa Heys btw I was wondering when WWWJDIC http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E7%89%A9 lists "他の物" as "たのもの", does it mean that "たのもの" is also a *fixed-phrase* that has a different nuance/meaning from "ほかのもの"
?

Comment: @Pacerier It is not a fixed phrase. It means the same.

Answer (score 2):

First I want you to know you are asking about what people would call the difference between on-reading and kun-reading (音読み versus 訓読み), which are ancient chinese (or sino-japanese, as my professor refers it) reading and (traditional) japanese reading respectively. **Simply speaking, chinese originated words (or parts) are pronounced in sino-Japanese ways. japanese originated words are pronounced in traditional Japanese ways.** and that was **supposed** to be the grand, master, iron rule of pronouncing things in Japanese

Second is, the state of Japanese is defined on a "**sort of** as-is" basis, that is to say, while there are some unclear rules, whatever people are used to reading in practice, it may become regulation. This is why you see these different readings. Rendaku(連濁, or sequential voicing, another thing that might change the pronunciation of a word) is a wonderful example of a twisted (metaphorically) morphology rule in Japanese. Japanese people sometimes deliberately play with the pronunciation of a kanji to express even more meanings than it already have.

**So what I would recommend is, do it the hard way, learn a lot of words, before you start guessing.(as opposed to trying to find a general rule)**

Back to your answer. I think you sort of got it in your two rules, they are two special cases of two meta-rules.

1, prefix can be associated to an on-reading because words that are pronounced in sino-japanese are either of chinese origin, or japanese-made-chinese word.

**This is why you feel they are always prefix of something**: most chinese words have two chinese charecters.

2, On the opposite, when a kanji **stands alone**　as a word or with a kana on its side, it is more likely a kun-reading word. "hokano hito" is a good example because the kanji 他 is alone. But relating it with the use of "no" might not be such a good idea. because no connects nouns, and nouns are.... nasty.

Again, there are many exceptions to my rule 1 and 2, I know you guys are gonna list it any way, so i might as well provide some:

To your second question: not all kanji can distinguish meaning with its pronunciation alone in a word. and unfortunately i find it hard to do so with 他.

You can often tell the origin and sound changes happened along the history though, which nobody cares unless you are linguist or really, really love the language.

btw there are more readings of this kanji that are not used, thought you might be interested. from http://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%96

［音］タ（呉）（漢）　［訓］ほか　あだし
［名のり］(<-that's for people's names)おさ・ひと

Edit:
I would definitely read 他の物 "hokano mono" because its less confusing. ta+no become the head/stem of words such as "tano-mu" "tano-mashii", which both have a tail started with m.