# Which reading of その他 is more common?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

What is the actual common reading of その他? Is it そのほか or そのた? Are there differences in social or grammatical context, or a nuance in the actual meaning?

- スーパー大辞林 doesn’t list その他 as a word. There is an example with その― for ほか, but not for た.
- ウィズダム和英辞典 lists そのほか only as a link to そのた.
- Yomikatawa simply says そのほか.
- Weblio contains some entries beginning both with そのほか and そのた, some of them with the other as a variant and others without it. By itself it is listed as そのほか with そのた as a variant.

I wasn’t able to abstract any rule, but I’m still not sure whether they’re freely interchangeable.

Comment: そのほか is more common in my experience, but I think ほか isn't actually a 常用 reading of 他

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [Reading (and usage) of 他: when is it 【た】, when is it 【ほか】?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2842/reading-and-usage-of-%e4%bb%96-when-is-it-%e3%81%9f-when-is-it-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%8b)